# c++ how to conserve vector items and double-precision

Tags: c++, vector, precision

I'm trying to fill a vector of an object Point 3D. My app read a csv file to load the vector by the three cordinate x, y, z. I use the type float.
This is my code.

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *theFileName = "file.csv"; //[100];
    vector<Point> v = getPointCloud(theFileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        v.at(i).print(cout);
    }

}
```

**getPointCloud**

```
vector<Point> getPointCloud(char *fileName) {
    string line;
    string token;
    vector<Point> v;
    double tab[3];
    ifstream file(fileName);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            int cpt = 0;
            stringstream stream(line);
            while (getline(stream, token, ',')) {
                tab[cpt] = ::atof(token.c_str());
                cpt++;
            }
            Point p(tab[0], tab[1], tab[2]);
            p.print(cout);            <-- the display works 
            p.setColor(255, 0, 0);
            v.push_back(p);
        }
        file.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Unable to open " << fileName << '\n';
        exit(0);
    }

    return v;
}
```

I have two problems:

1 - when I try to display points in the main method, I found that the three coordinates are null ( == 0) but in the displaying in the getPointCloud method works very well.

2 - Can someone give a simple method to conserve my coordinates without loss precision after mathematical operations. I have searched in the net but I don't understand haw to solve it. I'm newbie with c++.

**Point.h**

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

class Point {
protected:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    // color RGB
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
public:
    // Constructors
    Point();
    //  Point(const Point& orig);
    Point(std::ostream &strm);
    Point(float x, float y, float z);
    Point(const Point& orig);
    virtual ~Point();

    //getters

    float getX() const {
        return this->x;
    }

    float getY() const {
        return this->y;
    }

    float getZ() const {
        return this->z;
    }

    float getR() const {
        return this->r;
    }

    float getG() const {
        return this->g;
    }

    float getB() const {
        return this->b;
    }

    //setters

    void setX(float x) {
        this->x = x;
    }

    void setY(float y) {
        this->y = y;
    }

    void setZ(float z) {
        this->z = z;
    }

    void setR(float r) {
        this->r = r;
    }

    void setG(float g) {
        this->g = g;
    }

    void setB(float b) {
        this->b = b;
    }

    void setColor(float r, float g, float b) {
        this->r = r;
        this->g = g;
        this->b = b;
    }

    /**
     * Print the point
     * @param strm
     */
    void print(std::ostream &strm);

    //Other methods

    float dist2D(Point &other);

    float dist3D(Point &other);

    Point swap(Point p);

//    Point operator-(const Point &other) const;
};

#endif  /* POINT_H */
```

**Point.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Point.h"

Point::Point(const Point& orig) {
}

Point::Point(ostream &strm) {
    strm << "Type the abscissa: ", cin >> this->x;
    strm << "Type the ordinate: ", cin >> this->y;
    strm << "Type the applicate: ", cin >> this->z;
}

Point::Point(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {
    // The default point color is blue
    this->r = 0;
    this->g = 0;
    this->b = 255;
}

/**
 * Destructor
 */
Point::~Point() {

}

//Other methods

float Point::dist2D(Point &other) {
    float xd = x - other.x;
    float yd = y - other.y;
    return sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd);
}

float Point::dist3D(Point &other) {
    float xd = x - other.x;
    float yd = y - other.y;
    float zd = z - other.z;
    return sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd + zd * zd);
}

Point Point::swap(Point p) {
    Point aux(x, y, z);
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
    z = p.z;
    return aux;
}

//Point Point::operator-(const Point &other) const {
//    return Point(other.getX() - this->x, other.getY() - this->y, other.getZ() - this->z);
//}

void Point::print(ostream &strm) {
    strm << "Point(" << this->x << "," << y << "," << z << ")" << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show definition of the `Point` class? I suspect it has definition of a copy `constructor` which loses data.

Comment: `p.setColor` sets new values, overwriting what you had before. Try doing `p.print` after `p.setColor` to check this.

Comment: If your loop to set `tab[cpt]` runs more than 3 times, the behaviour is undefined. You should add in a check that you never access behind `tab[2]`, and probably also take some action if there were fewer than 3 times on the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Point::Point(const Point& orig) {
}
```

is incorrect.
It does not copy data from `orig` to `*this`

Please copy each of the member in this constructor.

This would look like this:

```
Point::Point(const Point& orig) {
    x = orig.x ;
    y = orig.y ;
    x = orig.z ;

    r = orig.r ;
    g = orig.g ;
    b = orig.b ;
}
```

Comment: @Dinosaur I am assuming you would like to keep 'double' but you store it as 'float', right?

Comment: The coordinates type are double but I have searched about conserving precision and I don't found solution. So I switched it to float and it is still the same problem.

Comment: So you say that you wrote coords inside of the file that is truncated, right? Have you tried `long double`? There is `atolf` function but I am not sure if it is standard.